# python pandas frequency table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

- subject
- school
- passed (True/False, for passing the subject)

Each row is a student. For each school, I want to get the percent of students passing for each school by subject. So I'd like a pivot table with a rows as schools, columns as subjects and values as fraction passing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html):

```
df.pivot_table(rows='school', values='passed', cols='subject')
```

Default `func` parameter is `mean`, so you don't have to override it:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'subject':['CS', 'Biology', 'Math', 'CS', 'CS'], 'school':['Stanford', 'Princeton', 'Stanford', 'Stanford', 'Stanford'], 'passed':[True,True,True,False,False]})
>>> df.pivot_table(rows='school', values='passed', cols='subject')
subject    Biology        CS  Math
school                            
Princeton        1       NaN   NaN
Stanford       NaN  0.333333     1
```

Comment: see the example, it totally works for bools. You can use your own aggfunc if you wish